# Grafana/Multi-Select Tagging: group metrics according to part of metric segment

Tags: graphite, grafana

I have Grafana (version 2.5.0-pre1) with Graphite as data source.

I'm trying to make use of templated dashboards (http://docs.grafana.org/reference/templating/) and multi-select tagging.

My metrics look like this:

```
backend.server01a_domain_com.la1
backend.server02a_domain_com.la1
backend.server01b_domain_com.la1
backend.server02b_domain_com.la1
backend.server01c_domain_com.la1
backend.server02c_domain_com.la1
```

I have variable `$hostname` filled by query `backend.*`, and it works fine.

I'd also like to group servers like this:

```
group_a: server0[12]a_domain_com
group_b: server0[12]b_domain_com
group_c: server0[12]c_domain_com
```

Is it possible to achieve with Multi-Select Tagging?

For now I can't find a way to select only part of metric segment with Tags query. And if I could have a tag with values `a`, `b`, `c`, would it be possible to use such a tag for metric search? `backend.server*$group_domain_com` looks like it uses variable `$group_domain_com`, not `$group`

Comment: I think your life would be a lot simpler if you split you hostname from the group in two separate nodes.

Comment: Thanks for suggestion, but unfortunately it's not an option in my case. In fact, I don't control these metrics and their names.